# when sleep used on a spawned process it kills the process

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec

I am primarily a java guy tinkering with Process.spawn and have hit a bit of a wall. Basically I tossed together a few rspec classes that do puts to tinker with it. This worked pretty well. Then I tossed a sleep in and the whole process just dies when a sleep is reached. I am not sure why, I thought that spawning gets around the shared resource issues of threads. Below is what I was using to make the processes

```
test_files = Dir["../spec/*.rb"]
test_files.each do |file|
  pid = Process.spawn("rspec #{file}")
  p pid
end
Process.wait
```

There is very little going on with the tests in the spec, below is a sample one.

```
it 'should another thing' do
 sleep(0.3)
 p "another1"
end
```

Could someone be so kind as to explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I'm assuming you think it's not working because you get something like this:

```
script.rb:6:in `wait': No child processes (Errno::ECHILD)
from script.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

And I'm assuming you get that because you have this script in maybe a lib directory or something, but you're running it from the root of your app,  so when it does `Dir["../spec/*.rb"]` you're expecting it to go up to the root of your app, and then down into the `spec` directory, but it is based on your pwd, so it goes to the parent directory of the app and looks for a spec directory, which doesn't exist.

Some things I'd advocate in this scenario, check that it finds the files before trying to spawn them. Use absolute filepaths, unless you intentionally want it to be based on where you run the program from. If this is all true, try writing it like this:

```
spec_glob  = File.expand_path('../spec/*.rb', __dir__)
test_files = Dir[spec_glob]
p test_files
test_files.each do |file|
  pid = Process.spawn("rspec #{file}")
  p pid
end
Process.wait
```